# Angular ui-router dynamic querystring definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have a search page and we have thousands of search attributes that can define by an admin panel. A characteristic search result page has a url like that:

```
http://example.com/search?a12=3213&a314=412412&a247=1941829&....
```

When we want to implement that page as a SPA with AngularJS by using `angular-ui-router`, I couldn't understand, how can we define that route configuration and how can we read all search parameters from querystring. Because `ui-router` forces to define every queryparam possibilities on route configuration to use them in `$stateParams`.

```
$stateProvider.state('search', {
    url: '/search?a1&a2&a3&a4&a5' // what about a1314?
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams.a1314);
    }
});
```

Do you know a workaround?

Comment: I believe there is no official solution yet: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/84, but there are some workarounds like this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/202

Answer (score 2):

you can use $location.search() in `url: '/search'` search route's `controller`

it return search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.

```
var searchObject = $location.search();

// => {a12: '3213', a314: '412412'}

console.log(searchObject .a12); //3213
```

and for route you can use

```
 url: '/search*'
```

so it will match

Comment: The main problem is, if a url comes with a query param that not defined in route config, ui-router removes it from url and shows page without it.

Comment: How will I generate a link to that url?