# Force ui-router to reload on querystring changes

Tags: angularjs, query-string, angular-ui-router

I have a state defined something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("app.search", {
    url: "/search?q",
    templateUrl: "App/Search.html",
    controller: "SearchController as vm",
});
```

When I want to navigate to the search page and specify a search term, I can do something like this:

```
$location.path("search").search({ q: "stuff" });
```

Which effective resolves to a url along the lines of `#/search?q=stuff`. If I then change the search term to "things", the search page correctly reactivates and searches as expected.

However, I'd like to be able to specify "random" querystring parameters *which have not been defined in my url*, and then have those parameters also reload the state. (Note: this is why I'm using `$location.path` instead of `$state.go` to change the URL). So for example, if I was searching for food, my URL may be:

```
#/search?q=stuff&type=food
```

And then I may be filtering on spice levels, which may change the URL to:

```
#/search?q=stuff&type=food&spice=medium
```

(etc).

The problem though, is that since I haven't defined all the other query string parameters (`type` and `spice` in this example), ui-router doesn't reload my page.

I can't use `$state.go` with `{ reload: true }` because it ignores the unspecified parameters.

**Is there a way I can trigger a page reload using "unspecified" querystring parameters?** [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696135/angular-ui-router-dynamic-querystring-definition) suggests I can make the route `/search*` but that doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a nice way to do this yet with ui-router. If you're willing to sacrifice your integrity a little bit you could utilize an alternate format for your query params. You can use a single http url query param object and list all your criteria using a custom format.

e.g.

```
/search/q?stuff:type=food:spice=cinnamon
```

The route setup would look like:

```
$stateProvider.state("app.search", {
    url: "/search?q",
    templateUrl: "App/Search.html",
    controller: "SearchController as vm",
});
```

and to navigate with the extra parameters:

```
$state.go('app.dashboard', { q: 'stuff:type=dessert:spice=cinnamon'});
```

to access the parameters on the route:

```
$state.params.q
```

You can then just parse out the 'stuff' value and then each name/value pair that was passed in.

PS> I'm not sure whether the colon (:) separator is valid but it was used to illustrate the proposed idea.

Comment: Definitely not the approach I wanted to go with but seems to be the only way I can find to make it work reliably. Thanks!